# Execute a role with roles and tasks

Tags: ansible

I have next playbook

```
---
- hosts:grupo1
  tasks:
    - name: Print a message
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "this task runs before the example role"

    - name: Include the example role
      include_role:
        name: inicializar

    - name: Print a message
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "this task runs after the example role"
...
```

Each time I launch it (`ansible-playbook UUAA/ECDY/playbooks/CIR_TIBCO_EI_PP_PR_MASTER.yml --extra-var "entorno=DESARROLLO build=1.2.3.4"`), I get following error:

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each: JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML. mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

The error appears to be in '/home/javi/UUAA/ECDY/playbooks/CIR_TIBCO_EI_PP_PR_MASTER.yml': line 3, column 8, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

hosts:grupo1 tasks: ^ here

any idea what is worong?

Answer (score 0):

Space is missing between the key and the value. Fix it

```yaml
- hosts: grupo1
```